# Screenshot capture from monitors with different resolutions in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dpi

I want to take a **screenshot** of the user's **currently active window** (and run OCR on top of it at a later stage). This (e.g. described [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/)) works fine as long as the developer works on standard monitors with the same resolution.

The problem is, that WPF uses **device-independent units** and the native API functions require **pixels**. I found many resources how to fix this for my own WPF application, most prominantly [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/03/07/getting-system-dpi-in-wpf-app.aspx) and [here](http://dzimchuk.net/post/Best-way-to-get-DPI-value-in-WPF). However, I found no way to do this dependent on what monitor the window is currently shown. For example, if the developer has a laptop with a QHD dipslay and uses a secondary monitor with a normal HD resolution. I found a C++ solution on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee308410(v=vs.85).aspx), but not in C#.

Does anyone have experience with this or any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use native functions. You'll find several SO questions that ask how to capture a screenshot. The answer is to get the screen's Graphics object and copy its contents  to a bitmap using .NET Graphic commands

Comment: BTW why OCR? You can use the accessibility APIs to get the contents of all visible windows. If an accessibility utility can do access the kind of information you want, so can your code.

Comment: Yes, I can do a screenshot of the current window. And I found out how to get the dpiX and dpiY value from Graphics.FromHwnd(...). But, this only does it for one monitor and not the one where the currently active window is on...

Comment: I tried that too, but without success, see my SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796974/get-the-content-of-any-active-window Thanks.

Comment: You can get all screens with [Screen.AllScreens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then copy the contents one-by-one.

Comment: thanks. And can I find out on what screen the currently active Window is on?

Comment: btw, talking about accessing windows' content via accessibility apis: do you maybe have a link/tutorial? I didn't find something from that I could successfully use... Thank you!