# Taking input in c sharp program from another screen

Tags: c#

I have to develop a data base for calling center, they have a software provided by the company. when ever they get a call the number of caller is shown in a minor screen inside that calling program.

I have to take that caller ID as input for my database in order to save and search the address and other information about user.
A friend told me about Auto IT that you can take this type of input but i want to create it in c #, i dont even know what to search for it. can someone point me to right direction ? or share some example

Edit: suggestion given by one as i have to use the image processing. Thats the only way to solve this problem. No other solution yet.

What about the auto IT, can we do it easily from that ? i really dont want to get in to image processing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read another windows from a different program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685002/how-to-read-another-windows-from-a-different-program)

Comment: The trick will be to find out if the data are in a windows element which you can access and read out or if they are only painted; in the latter case you would have to capture the pixels and try to ocr them to text.. Try to [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=c%23+read+text+from+other+application&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Lw3cVdHoLqH_ygOdhpmwDg) like this..!

Comment: Note that I did __not__ sugest to go for image processing! It would only be the last resort if you can't get at the element.Text! This will depend on how the other program works!