# multi Clipboard in C#(Windows Application)

Tags: c#

I want to Copy Text from Other Windows and Paste in a Textbox in My C# Application,But there is a problem,When I copy text to ClipBoard,My Clipboard cleans,I want to create another Clipboard to solve this problem but how?>
tell to windows save copied Data in Other space?And After That,get Copied Data From the space,And Reload Clipboard With previous copied Data.Thanks for yOur Help.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. It is not a place to dump your to-do list.

Comment: You could make a keylogger and listen for your key combination and then copy the original clipboard. and to print it use sendkeys. because I assume it is very hard to read data from a window

Answer (score 0):

Check MSDN documentation for [`Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

You should be able to resolve your problem with [`GetDataObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdataobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SetDataObject(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs5ebdfz(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Example (untested):

```
var previousData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
// TODO: copy text to your clipboard as you already do.
Clipboard.SetDataObject(previousData, true);
// TODO: proceed with usual operations.
```

Depending on the situation, you might even be able to solve the problem without using the clipboard. For instance by directly [inserting text into the textbox of your application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4539187/1135019) or [reading from another program's window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8685002/1135019).