# Visual Studio C# NuGet Package That was installed cannot be found with "using"

Tags: c#, nuget, package-managers, autoit-c#-wrapper

I wanted to install the nuget package `AutoItX.Dotnet` after looking at an answer in another stack overflow post

[How to read another windows from a different program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685002/how-to-read-another-windows-from-a-different-program)

I installed it to my Visual Studio project using the NuGet Package manager, I installed it for the current solution I was working on. However when I go to include `using AutoIt`, it cannot find it. How can I get this package to install properly?

Comment: Have you tried `using AutoItX`?

Comment: This sounds like an assembly reference issue. I'm not sure that installing the package adds the assembly to the project references. And if not then the using isn't going to work.

Comment: @AndrewWynn I just tried this and it did not fix it

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Is there a way I can install it to work with using? I am trying to follow the answer on the other SO post I put above. Or is there a way to get the AutoIt classes to work another way?

Comment: Go to the "references" node in solution explorer and on the right click menu select "Add Reference" and go from there, finding the assembly the package installed.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I do not see a references tab, I just see Dependencies

Comment: Which is the problem, this Nuget package is very old and has a dependency on .NET 2.0 assemblies.  It cannot work in a project that targets .NET 5+.  Use one of the project templates that has ".NET Framework" in its name.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, creating a new project with (.NET Framework) type fixed my issue.